# Get Token from API with Basic Auth on Xamarin forms c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have this project that I need to call an API from my Xamarin forms Application in order to receive a Token. The encoded is the encrypted username and password for Basic Auth. The code below works properly, but sometimes it does not receive a Token and throws me an error

> Error: ConnectFailure (Network is unreachable).

Is there a different way I can receive the token? Maybe an alternative way to do it.

```cs
string username;
string password;
string webip;
string port;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var formData = "var1=val1&var2=val2";
var encodedFormData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formData);
String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}:{1}/{2}"
                                        , SettingsServices.WebIP
                                        , SettingsServices.WebPort
                                        , SettingsServices.tokenAPI));
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = encodedFormData.Length;
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
      stream.Write(encodedFormData, 0, encodedFormData.Length);
}
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
token = response.Headers["Token"];
tokenExpiry = Convert.ToInt32(response.Headers["TokenExpiry"]);
tokenTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes((tokenExpiry / 60) - 1);
```

Comment: that sounds like a transient network problem - you should probably catch the exception and retry the request

Comment: Hey Jason, when I tried with the global IP it worked properly. But this error did not happen before.

Comment: Its the internet. Sometimes glitches happen, sometimes they don't. "error did not happen before" could be anything. Or nothing. As Jason suggests, design the code to handle it if it happens. If you catch the error, try the call three times in a row, and it still fails - then there might be some deeper problem.

Comment: It was a network problem indeed.